# How to pass data from one angular 4 app to another?

Tags: angular

I have 2 angular 4 app deployed on same server, both having different context roots. 
Booking app accessible at /booking/
Map app accessible at /map
Note: These are not 2 routes of single angular app.
I need to pass some data from booking to map application.
Earlier it was non angular single app and data was getting submitted using form post method.

Comment: two different app can communicate through `socket` or `api`. So, you have to choose one.

Comment: will you be able to post any example link? @SteveRuben